# Dask load and apply funtion on read_csv

Tags: python, dask

I'm trying to load a **.csv of 4 GB of size** with **125 Millions of rows** and 5 types of data on my computer that have this feautures:

- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E7200 @ 2.53 GHz
- RAM: 8 GB DDR3 @ 1833 MHz
- HD:500 GB 7200 rpm
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04

When I run this code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

dtypes = {'item_nbr':'int32', 'store_nbr':'int8', 'onpromotion':'bool' }
df_train = dd.read_csv('data/train.csv', dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=["date"], 
converters={'unit_sales': lambda u: np.log1p(float(u)) if float(u) > 0 else 0}, 
usecols=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).compute()
```

My PC just freeze and I need to restart it, Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Edition:

Currently I'm trying to run:  `df_train.unit_sales.map_partitions(np.log1p).compute()` 
And my PC still freezing, So,How Can I calculate the logaritm of all 125 Million of rows without freezing my PC? and, How do I check to see if it's safe to call compute?

Comment: This isn't surprising. The moment you call `.compute()`, you trigger a computation that brings all data into memory. This will likely yield MemoryError. Typically, you should think about how you want the result and see if you can trigger `compute()` on smaller sets of data after filtering.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `nrows` and `skiprows` to read your csv by blocks?

Comment: Yes, I can use skiprows, but I would like to transforme the entire dataset and then filter it. So, Is a good solution to use chunksize? and with a "for" funtion iterate all dataset?

Comment: How will you *save* your output? Saving a 4GB file at the end of your computations may be memory-intensive. If the result is going to feed into another calculation and it's chunkable, that's one way to go.

Comment: I need calculate the logaritm of all unit_sales before to make another transformations, So the final output is a result of Machine Learning prediction estimators.

Comment: You can split your data frame into several files, e.g. read using a defined chunk size and save into a new file, then trasform each of the new files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, when you call `.compute()` on a dask dataframe you are saying "I am done now, please turn this into a pandas object"

In your case you probably don't want to do this right away, you want to do this after you perform other queries, aggregations, etc..

#### bad

```
df = dd.read_csv('lots-of-data-*.csv')
df = df.compute()  # this is very large and may not fit in memory
```

#### good

```
df = dd.read_csv('lots-of-data-*.csv')
df = df[df.value > 0]
result = df.groupby('name').value.mean()
result = result.compute()  # this is probably much smaller
```

Comment: Thanks! However, If I want to apply a funtion to calculate the logaritm of each value of one column, How can I do that? I'm trying with: df_train.apply(lambda x: np.log1p(x), axis=1 , meta={'unit_sales':'float32'}).compute()

Comment: I recommend asking that as a separate question on Stack Overflow